# Initialising a c with int as EOF and then using it for getchar()?

Tags: c, while-loop, int, eof, getchar

The title pretty much says it all. I have this code for the homework (sent by the lecturer) which is for a spellchecker and I do not see the reason for c being an int initialized with EOF and then using it for getchar()? This is new to me, thank you! (I do not have anything inside the while because it is my assignment to put code there and I got stuck at the question above)

```
 int c = EOF;
 while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {

  }
```

EDIT: I was told the EOF is just so that it doesn't enter the while if there is no input but doesn't make sense to me since if c doesn't use getchar the while is still unused

Comment: `while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {`  What exactly do you gain by cramming all that into one line?

Comment: I do not see a reason to initialize `c` to `EOF` too.

Comment: I don't see a reason to finish the loop when a NUL character is encountered.

Comment: `c` has to be an int because that's what getchar() returns. the initialization, however, is useless because it's immediately followed by an assignment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle dunno either

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker So far I've only initialized variables with char when using getchar(), thought it has to be a char.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker " however, is useless because it's immediately followed by an assignment." --> Some coding standards (sane or not) required all objects to be initialized.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is a well known pattern and is concise while remaining readable

Answer (score 0):

The initialization is **not** functionally required.

It has the nice attribute of having `c` with an initialized value.  Useful for debugging and avoiding otherwise uninitialized object errors.  But in this case, code could have been `int c = 0;`, `int c;`, `int c = EOF;`, .... with no functional difference.

```
int c = EOF;
while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {
  ;
}
```

> OP: I was told the EOF is just so that it doesn't enter the while if there is no input but doesn't make sense to me since if c doesn't use getchar the while is still unused

If there is no input, `c = getchar()` will assigned `EOF` to `c`, overwriting the `EOF` initialization of `int c = EOF;`.  In this case, the loop body is not entered even without initialization.

---

Now the debate can move to "what should be done" as the initialization is not functionally required.  This and many like issues are best resolved by your group's coding standards.  Lacking a group standard, follow the lead of your customer (professor?).  Lacking that lead, go for what is simply:  `int c;`

---

`while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {` is an anti-pattern as it stops the loop when end-of-file occurs or if a *null character* is read. [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421781/initialising-a-c-with-int-as-eof-and-then-using-it-for-getchar/60422318#comment106888487_60421781)  The below is more common, but selection depends on your coding goals.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

---

> OP: So far I've only initialized variables with char when using getchar(), thought it has to be a char.

`int getchar(void);` typically returns 257 different values, `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` and `EOF`.  Saving that into a `char` loses information.  Use `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you describe it as an anti-pattern? Perhaps the intended behaviour is exactly what it does .

Comment: @M.M `while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {` looks similar to the common `while` loop to read _all_ characters of a file, yet differs -   this is a novel one to me with decades of experience - thus a potential anti-pattern.  It stops on one of 2 values, but not the common  `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {` to read a _line_, so it seemed helpful to caution OP that it might not be the right code.  True it might be correct, but I have reasonable doubts.  Would need more OP info to settle - yet that is closer to another question.